# How to style a `ListTile` to have specific left border AND color in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, listtile

Depending on `belongsToCluster` I style my `LisTile` accordingly.
When it is true, I'd like to round top-left and bottom-left corners while drawing the left side with a thick coloured border.

[UPDATED]

Here is an idea of what I try to achieve:

[image]

How can I do that?

Below is my current code:

```dart
        Color color = Colors.white;
        

        final borderRadius = const BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(32),
          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(32),
        );

        return ListTile(
          tileColor: Colors.indigo[400],

          shape: belongsToCluster
              
                  ? RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: borderRadius,
                      side: BorderSide(width: 10, color: color))
                  : Border(
                      left: BorderSide(
                      color: color,
                      width: 10.0,
                    ))),
          leading: containedIcon(),
          title: deviceName(),
          // blah blah
```

Comment: what is your issue then? did you forget to `setState`